# From a Twig template, how to retrieve the content of a HTTP header in the current request?

Tags: craft3, request, https, headers

I would like to detect if a header in the current request is present and obtain its value, directly within a Twig template. 
I know that `craft.app.request` gives access to a few variables like `isAjax` that directly check the headers content, but I haven't found a method to directly retrieve a specific header.

Can this be achieved in some way? (preferably not by writing a plugin)

Answer (score 4):

By checking the code, I could find a method named `getHeaders()` that will return all the headers of the current request.

So if you want to retrieve the content of the `foo` header, just use:

```
{% set headers = craft.app.request.getHeaders() %}
{% set fooHeader = headers['foo'] %}
```

Comment: Worth noting that attempting to access the `headers` variable as an array will result in a Twig Runtime Error, specifically `Key "foo" in object with ArrayAccess of class "yii\web\HeaderCollection" does not exist.`. Using the `get` method for the `HeaderCollection` is recommend, as follows, `{{ headers.get('foo') }}`

Answer (score 2):

[`craft.app.request.getHeaders()`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#public-methods) returns an instance of [`yii\web\HeaderCollection`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-headercollection#methods), which has a number of public methods you can use from a Twig template.

For example, to see if an `isAjax` header is present:

```php-template
{# Get the header collection #}
{% set headers = craft.app.request.getHeaders() %}

{# Test for specific header #}
{% set isAjaxRequest = headers.has('isAjax') %}

{% if isAjaxRequest %}
  {# Do something... #}
{% endif %}
```

If you need to read the value of a header, use the [`get()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-headercollection#get()-detail) method.